# What is the best approach to verify an XML Service response is part of another UniversalFileXML with lot of Nodes in java

Tags: java, xml, compare, subset

I have to perform 2 different tests first one is

Scenario 1. Compare 2 XML(I do not have the posible schema) considering some list nodes/tags could be in a different Order and show in the log if there is any difference or extra node.

Scenario 2- I have an Small XML service response and I have to verify that this response is correctly showed inside an Universal XML File that has too many nodes. I have to show what is the difference in the case that some error exist with a different value or wrong structure, considering some list nodes/tags could be in a different Order.

Ex. for scenario 2.

XML1 Service Response to be verified into Universal XML

```
<dinner_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Burrito</name>
        <price>$1.95</price>
        <description>Tortilla, avocado, beans, meat, cream</description>
        <calories>200</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Mexican Tacos</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>Order of 5 Mexican Tacos</description>
        <calories>450</calories>
    </food>
</dinner_menu>
```

XML2 Universal XML where the nodes are there but in a different order(this is ok but there is one error in the Mexican taco price node)

```
<AllServicesResponses>
<Service1Restaurant>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries </description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
<dinner_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Mexican Tacos</name>
        <calories>450</calories>
        <price>$8.50</prce>
        <description>Order of 5 Mexican Tacos</description>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Burrito</name>
        <price>$1.95</price>
        <description>Tortilla, avocado, beans, meat, cream</description>
        <calories>200</calories>
    </food>
</dinner_menu>
</Service1Restaurant1>
<Service2Response>
.<Node1></Node1>
.
.
</Service2Response>
<Service3Response>
.<Node1></Node1>
.
.
</Service3Response>

</AllServicesResponses>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your problem correctly, but have you considered writing a DTD and using standard XML validation to verify the XML correctness?

Comment: the first one I just solved with the help of XML Unit lbraries,  but the second one I treated as a different question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66557749/java-how-can-i-compare-2-xml-the-first-one-contains-a-node-with-the-structure-of